# How do I share common web resources between web applications is spring mvc

Tags: java, spring, web-applications, war

I want to develop two web applications having common web resources like css, js and jsp files. How can I share these files between two java web application. I am using Spring-MVC.
One possible solution is to make a share web application and share it in two projects. But it is not possible to add a war file as dependency.

Comment: Are you using Maven?

Comment: Yes. I am using maven

Comment: Try the overlay feature from maven-war-plugin: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/overlays.html